# Turn table-element into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I would like to turn a table into a `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
URL = 'https://ladieseuropeantour.com/reports-page/?tourn=1202&tclass=rnk&report=tmscores~season=2015~params=P*4ESC04~#/profile'
```

The element in question is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get(URL)
ranking = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='maintablelive']")
```

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html(ranking.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
```

I am also using the dropdown-menu to select multiple rounds. When a different round is selected, `driver.current_url` doesn't change so I think it's not possible to load these new tables with `requests` or anything.

Please advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `selenium`, you want to access the URL's API endpoint.

**Finding the API endpoint**

You can trace it as follows:

- Open the URL in Chrome
- Use `Ctrl + Shift + J` to open DevTools, navigate to `Network`, select `Fetch/XHR` from the sub navbar, and refresh the URL.
- This will reload the network connections, and when you click on one of the lines that will appear, you can select `Response` from the second sub navbar to see if they are returning data.
- Going through them, we can locate the connection that is responsible for returning the data for the table, namely https://ladieseuropeantour.com/api/let/cache/let/2015/2015-1202-scores-P*4ESC04.json (you can leave out the query part `?randomadd=1673086921319` at the end).

[image: DevTools]

Now, with this knowledge, we can simply load all the data with `requests`, investigate the type of information that is contained in the `JSON` and dump the required sub part in a `df`.

For example, let's recreate the table from your URL. This one:

[image: Table URL]

**Code**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ladieseuropeantour.com/api/let/cache/let/2015/2015-1202-scores-P*4ESC04.json'

data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data['scores']['scores_entry'])
cols = ['pos','name','nationality','vspar',
        'score_R1','score_R2','score_R3','score_R4', 'score']

df_table = df.loc[:,cols]
df_table.head()

  pos                    name nationality vspar score_R1 score_R2 score_R3  \
0   1          Lydia Ko (NZL)         NZL    -9       70       70       72   
1   2          Amy Yang (KOR)         KOR    -7       73       70       70   
2   3  Ariya Jutanugarn (THA)         THA    -4       69       71       72   
3   4        Jenny Shin (KOR)         KOR    -2       76       71       74   
4   4         Ilhee Lee (KOR)         KOR    -2       68       82       69   

  score_R4 score  
0       71   283  
1       72   285  
2       76   288  
3       69   290  
4       71   290
```

If you check `print(df.columns)`, you'll see that the main `df` contains all the data that lies behind all of the tables you can select on the URL. So, have a go at that to select whatever you are looking for.